# bootstrap modal doesn't pass the data properly

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to pass the data of my books every time I click the button 'Summary' but it pass only the data of the first book, all the others that i click the button on the still show the data of the first book.

book.component.html

```
<body>
<div class="search-hero">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="search" [(ngModel)]="searchText" autocomplete="off"
  placeholder="&#61442;  Start searching for a book by name, price or type" />
 </div>
 <div class="container" *ngFor="let item of books | filter: searchText">
 <img src="{{ item.image }}" alt="img" class="image" />
  <div class="overlay overlayFade">
  <div class="text">
    <label>Book Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name" [(ngModel)]="item.name"
      [disabled]="isAfford ? false : true" />
    <label>Category</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter category" [(ngModel)]="item.category"
      [disabled]="isAfford ? false : true" />
    <label>Price</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter price" [(ngModel)]="item.price"
      [disabled]="isAfford ? false : true" />
    <label>Amount</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter amount" [(ngModel)]="item.amount"
      [disabled]="isAfford ? false : true" />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" *ngIf="canPurchase" (click)="purchaseBook(item)">
      Purchase
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" (click)="updateBook(item)" *ngIf="isAfford">
      Update
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteBook(item.id)">
      Delete
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
      Summary
    </button>
    <div class="alert alert-success" *ngIf="message">{{ message }}</div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
    labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{item.name}}</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        {{item.summary}}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   </div>
  </body>
```

books.component.ts

```
import { CustomerService } from './../../services/customer.service';
import { AdminService } from './../../services/admin.service';
import { LoginService } from './../../services/login.service';
import { AuthorService } from './../../services/author.service';
import { Book } from './../../models/book';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-books',
 templateUrl: './books.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./books.component.css'],
 })
export class BooksComponent implements OnInit {
 modalForm: FormGroup;
 searchText: string;
 message: string;
 public canPurchase = false;
 public authorID: number;
 public email: string;
 public password: string;
 public book = new Book();
 public books: Book[] = [];
 public type: string;
 public isAfford = false;
 id: number = 0;
 constructor(
   private authorService: AuthorService,
   private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute,
   private loginService: LoginService,
   private router: Router,
   private adminService: AdminService,
   private customerService: CustomerService
    ) { }

   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.type = this.loginService.type;
    if (this.type === 'Author') {
      this.authorService
    .getAuthorID(this.loginService.email, this.loginService.password)
    .subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.authorID = res;
        this.getAllBooks();
      },
      (err) => {
        alert(err.message);
      }
       );
     this.isAfford = true;
   }
  if (this.type === 'Admin') {
   this.id = 1;
   this.isAfford = false;
   this.getAllBooks();
 }
 if (this.type === 'Customer') {
   this.customerService
     .getCustomerID(this.loginService.email, this.loginService.password)
     .subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.id = res;
        this.getAllBooks();
      },
      (err) => {
        alert(err.message);
      }
    );
   this.canPurchase = true;
  }
 }

 resetForm() {
  this.modalForm.reset();
  console.log('reset');
}

 addBook() {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('add-book');
 }

 getOneBook(id: number) {
   this.authorService.getOneBook(id).subscribe(
    (res) => {
      this.book = res;
     },
     (err) => {
       alert(err.message);
     }
      );
    }

   purchaseBook(book: Book) {
    this.customerService.setCustomerID(this.id).subscribe(
     (res) => {
       this.customerService.purchaseBook(book).subscribe(
         (res) => {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('purchases');
         },
         (err) => {
          alert(err.message);
        }
       );
       },
         (err) => {
           alert(err.message);
       }
       );
       }

    updateBook(book: Book) {
     this.authorService.updateBook(book).subscribe(
      (res) => {
       this.book = res;
       this.message = book.name + ' update successfully!';
        setTimeout(() => {
        this.message = '';
       }  , 2000);
       },
     (err) => {
     alert(err.message);
     }
    );
    } 

     deleteBook(id: number) {
     this.authorService.deleteBook(id).subscribe(
      (res) => {
      this.books = this.books.filter((book) => book.id !== id);
       },
         (err) => {
         alert(err.message);
         }
       );
       }

    getAllBooks() {
      if (this.type === 'Author') {
       this.authorService.getAllBooks(this.authorID).subscribe(
         (res) => {
         this.books = res;
          },
          (err) => {
           alert(err.message);
          }
          );
         }
     if (this.type === 'Admin' || this.type === 'Customer') {
     this.adminService.getAllBooks().subscribe(
       (res) => {
         this.books = res;
       },
       (err) => {
        alert(err.message);
         }
       );
       }
      }

     }
```

Only the data of the first book is showing to me but if i cick on the other books summary is it still show me the data of the first book. thanks for the helpers

Comment: You are using the same `ID` for all the modals try changing the id sections to `[id]="'modal-'+index"` and the index to the loop.

Comment: Its better to have a common modal and trigger the modal from the ts file, so you wont have a bunch of markup in the browser when having so many books in the loop..